# Trying to implement priority queue for nearest neighbor search

Tags: c#, generics, tree, tuples, nearest-neighbor

So to give a bit of background:

- I am trying to implement a k-d tree with nearest neighbor search.
- To implement the NN search, I needed to create a priority queue.
- The priority queue has to have the point coordinates and the distance.
- So I decided to group those two into a Tuple.

Turns out C# is a bit different than the other languages I'm used to.

Here's the error message I get when I do this:

```
PriorityQueue<Tuple<Point, double>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Tuple<Point, double>>();
```

> error CS0311: The type `System.Tuple<Tree.Point,double>' cannot be
>   used as type parameter`T' in the generic type or method
>   `PriorityQueue.PriorityQueue<T>'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from`System.Tuple' to
>   `System.IComparable>'

I researched this for quite some time and since I'm new to C#, I can't quite understand why this is happening. I guess programming in Python makes life very easy.

---

My priority queue class looks like this:

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private List<T> dataHeap;

    public PriorityQueue()
    {
        this.dataHeap = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        this.dataHeap.Add(value);
        BubbleUp();
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (this.dataHeap.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot Dequeue from empty queue!");
        }

        T result = dataHeap[0];
        int count = this.dataHeap.Count - 1;
        dataHeap[0] = dataHeap[count];
        dataHeap.RemoveAt(count);
        ShiftDown();

        return result;
    }

    private void BubbleUp()
    {
        int childIndex = dataHeap.Count - 1;

        while (childIndex > 0)
        {
            int parentIndex = (childIndex - 1) / 2;

            if (dataHeap[childIndex].CompareTo(dataHeap[parentIndex]) >= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            SwapAt(childIndex, parentIndex);
            childIndex = parentIndex;
        }
    }

    private void ShiftDown()
    {
        int count = this.dataHeap.Count - 1;
        int parentIndex = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            int childIndex = parentIndex * 2 + 1;
            if (childIndex > count)
            {
                break;
            }

            int rightChild = childIndex + 1;
            if (rightChild <= count && dataHeap[rightChild].CompareTo(dataHeap[childIndex]) < 0)
            {
                childIndex = rightChild;
            }
            if (dataHeap[parentIndex].CompareTo(dataHeap[childIndex]) <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            SwapAt(parentIndex, childIndex);
            parentIndex = childIndex;
        }
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.dataHeap.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty.");
        }

        T frontItem = dataHeap[0];
        return frontItem;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return dataHeap.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>Removes all elements from the queue.</summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        this.dataHeap.Clear();
    }

    public void CopyToArray(T[] array, int index)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Array");
        }

        int length = array.Length;
        if (index < 0 || index >= length)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index must be between zero and array length.");
        }
        if (length - index < this.dataHeap.Count-1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Queue is bigger than array");
        }

        T[] data = this.dataHeap.ToArray();
        Array.Copy(data, 0, array, index, data.Length);
    }

    public bool IsConsistent()
    {
        if (dataHeap.Count == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        int lastIndex = dataHeap.Count - 1; 
        for (int parentIndex = 0; parentIndex < dataHeap.Count; ++parentIndex) 
        {
            int leftChildIndex = 2 * parentIndex + 1; 
            int rightChildIndex = 2 * parentIndex + 2;

            if (leftChildIndex <= lastIndex && dataHeap[parentIndex].CompareTo(dataHeap[leftChildIndex]) > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (rightChildIndex <= lastIndex && dataHeap[parentIndex].CompareTo(dataHeap[rightChildIndex]) > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void SwapAt(int first,int second)
    {
        T value = dataHeap[first];
        dataHeap[first] = dataHeap[second];
        dataHeap[second] = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string queueString = string.Join(" ", dataHeap.ToArray());
        return queueString;
    }
}
```

My Point class:

```
class Point : IComparable
{
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(double xCoord, double yCoord)
    {
        SetPoint(xCoord, yCoord);
    }

    ~Point() {}

    public int CompareTo(object obj) 
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Point p = obj as Point;
        if (p != null) 
            return (this.x.CompareTo(p.x) & this.y.CompareTo(p.y));
        else 
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Point");
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Point a, Point b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null)) return true;
        if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1]) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Point a, Point b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null)) return true;
        if (a[0] != b[0] || a[1] != b[1]) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public double this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index == 0) return x;
            else if (index == 1) return y;
            else throw new System.IndexOutOfRangeException("index " + index + " is out of range");
        }
        set
        {
            if (index == 0) x = value;
            else if (index == 1) y = value;
            else throw new System.IndexOutOfRangeException("index " + index + " is out of range");
        }

    }

    public void SetPoint(double xCoord, double yCoord)
    {
        x = xCoord;
        y = yCoord;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems rather self explanatory.  What about it don't you understand?  You've required that the type be comparable, and it hasn't defined itself as comparable.  Either use a type that is comparable, or change the data structure to not require the type be comparable.

Comment: Your `Point` class doesn't need a finaliser and should probably implement `IComparable<Point>` instead of the non-generic version. You should also consider making it a struct and making it immutable.

Comment: @Servy What I don't understand is that Tuple is comparable and I implement IComparable for my priority queue, so I don't see how that error message comes up. Excuse my ignorance, I've only been learning C# for a couple days.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi What makes you think that `Tuple` is comparable?  You've been given a pretty clear indication that it is not in fact comparable, which it is not.

Comment: @Servy So then what does MSDN mean by this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It implements `IComparable`, not `IComparable<T>`, which is the restriction that you applied in your container.

Comment: @Servy So it is impossible to create a truly generic priority queue that can handle all types?

Comment: @ChrisTarazi No.  You can't require that the type implement `IComparable<T>` if you want to create a container for types that don't implement it.  You should probably just accept an IComparer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you remove the constraint on `T` and then take an explicit `IComparer<T>` in the constructor for `PriorityQueue`. Your existing constructor can provide `Comparer<T>.Default` as the comparer if none is provided.

You then need to change `obj.CompareTo(other)` to `comp.Compare(obj, other)` throughout `PriorityQueue`.

```
public class PriorityQueue<T>
{
    private List<T> dataHeap;
    private readonly IComparer<T> comp;

    public PriorityQueue() : this(Comparer<T>.Default) {}

    public PriorityQueue(IComparer<T> comp)
    {
        this.dataHeap = new List<T>();
        this.comp = comp;
    }
    ...
    private void BubbleUp() {
        if (this.comp.Compare(dataHeap[childIndex], dataHeap[parentIndex]) >= 0)
   }
}
```